# Checking existence of Node with attribute value

Tags: java, xpath

I have this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Forms>
<Form ID="533" PhysDocID=""
    TemplateID="989">
    <topmostSubform ind="0">
        <TextField1 ind="3" />
        <NumOfCigar ind="0" />
        <Check1 ind="0">0</Check1>
        <Check1 ind="1">1</Check1>
        <Check1 ind="2">2</Check1>
        <Check1 ind="3">3</Check1>
        <Check1 ind="4">4</Check1>
        <Check1 ind="5">5</Check1>
        <Check1 ind="6">6</Check1>
        <Check1 ind="7">7</Check1>
    </topmostSubform>
</Form>
<Form ID="533" PhysDocID=""
    TemplateID="616">
    <topmostSubform ind="0">
    <Check1 ind="0">0</Check1>
        <Check1 ind="1">1</Check1>
        <Check1 ind="2">2</Check1>
        <Check1 ind="3">3</Check1>
    </topmostSubform>
</Form>
```

I want to check if my xml contains a Form with a "TemplateID" attribute value of "616".

Is there an xpath which returns true or false for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
"boolean(/Forms/Form[@TemplateID='616'])"
```

Or:

```
 "boolean(//Form[@TemplateID='616'])"
```